# How do I create a new BigInteger variable and make a method that returns a BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

```
BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(calcFib(Integer.parseInt(args[0])));
```

I try to run this to create a new BigInteger for a large Fibonacci number, but whenever I do, this error gets thrown:

```
error: cannot find symbol

    BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(calcFib(Integer.parseInt(args[0])));
    ^
symbol: class BigInteger

location: class FibonacciCalculator
```

I've imported java.lang.Object if that helps.  Am still new to programming so please don't judge :P

Edit: the original is done in main, however now I'm getting a new problem with this line of code after importing java.math.BigInteger

```
public static BigInteger calcFib (int n)
{
    if(n == 1 || n == 2)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        return calcFib(n-1) + calcFib(n-2);
    }
}
```

both parts of the if/else statements throw errors, the if says int can
't be converted to BigInteger, and the else says bad operand types.  Again sorry for my ignorance and thanks for the help!

Comment: Can u please add your method code where you are trying to do this?

Comment: It was in the main method, in which I declare my variables and print the BigInteger

Comment: just import java.math.BigInteger package

Comment: thanks Alok, I just did that and got more errors as shown in the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BigInteger` class is defined inside `java.math.BigInteger` so try to import `java.math.BigInteger`.

Answer (score 2):

In the second part of your question, you need to change the code slightly if you are using `BinIntegers` rather than the `int` or `long` types, as you can't use the usual `+` operator or automatically convert between `int` and `BigInteger`.

Revised code should look like this:

```
public static BigInteger calcFib(int n)
{
    if(n == 1 || n == 2)
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    else
    {
        return calcFib(n - 1).add(calcFib(n - 2));
    }
}
```

In an ideal world, you would probably also check for zero and negative numbers and handle these by throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked fine after that, now for the long haul of making my computer find the 999th fibonacci number. :P

Comment: Hi @Darth7urtle, I think you will be waiting approximately forever to calculate the 999th number using the branching recursive algorithm, as this will need approximately 2^999 (= approx 10^300) additions.  See if you can find a linear time complexity fib.

Comment: damn I never actually did the calculation for how many additions, thanks for the heads up! @msandiford